# Getting javascript unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, token

I have the following code in js:

```
<input type='button' id='cbtcancelar' name='Cancelar' value='Cancelar' onclick='cancela(" + pidm + ",\"" + correo + "\",\"" + cubiculo + "\",\"" + horario + "\",\"" + otros + "\");' />";
```

I get unexpected token when i press the cbtcancelar button, but i cant get what it is, thanks

Any idea'

Comment: What are `pidm`, `correo` etc? Javascript variables?

Comment: You say `code in js` but your example code starts as plain HTML and then mixes with js elements "out of nowhere". Please complete your code accordingly

Comment: yes pidm, correo  are variables.

Comment: this is the complete string in js

Comment: document.getElementById('cbotones').innerHTML = "<input id='cbtguardar' type='button' name='Guardar' value='Guardar' onclick='validar_campos2(" + pidm + ");' /><input type='button' id='cbtcancelar' name='Cancelar' value='Cancelar' onclick='cancela(" + pidm + ",\"" + correo + "\",\"" + cubiculo + "\",\"" + horario + "\",\"" + otros + "\");' />"

Comment: Your `";` at the end of your HTML code suggests that we are looking at a piece of **javascript** code. A **string** you are trying to create **inside javascript**, which contains **HTML**, to be used elsewhere. Do you want to pass the text "pidm" etc to the string, or do you want to pass the *value*  of pidm etc in your string? More context = more lines of your code would really help here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing unless those are server variables you need this:

```
 <input type='button' id='cbtcancelar' name='Cancelar' value='Cancelar' onclick='cancela(pidm, correo, cubiculo, horario, otros);' />";
```

I see this was javascript not html, ok, this seemed to work for me.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var pidm = 0;
            var correo = "correo";
            var cubiculo = "cubiculo";
            var horario = "horario";
            var otros = "otros";
            var stuff = "<input id='cbtguardar' type='button' name='Guardar' value='Guardar' onclick='validar_campos2(" + pidm + ");' /><input type='button' id='cbtcancelar' name='Cancelar' value='Cancelar' onclick='cancela(" + pidm + ",\"" + correo + "\",\"" + cubiculo + "\",\"" + horario + "\",\"" + otros + "\");' />";
            alert(stuff);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: document.getElementById('cbotones').innerHTML = "<input id='cbtguardar' type='button' name='Guardar' value='Guardar' onclick='validar_campos2(" + pidm + ");' /><input type='button' id='cbtcancelar' name='Cancelar' value='Cancelar' onclick='cancela(" + pidm + ",\"" + correo + "\",\"" + cubiculo + "\",\"" + horario + "\",\"" + otros + "\");' />"

Comment: If this doesn't work, you might need to include more code.  Hard to pinpoint the issue with the minimal code you gave.